# Java preparedstatement slower than sql developer

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm performing a call to an Oracle database using java and JDBC like this:

```
PreparedStatement prep=c.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT a.user FROM  data a where a.start_time >=? " +
    "and a.end_time <=? and a.operation='UPDATE USER'");

prep.setString(1, 02-MAR-15);
prep.setString(2, 03-MAR-15);
ResultSet rs=prep.executeQuery();
```

This query is taking over 44 seconds in returning 560 values.

Here is the same query run in SQL Developer:

```
SELECT a.user FROM  data a where a.start_time >='02-MAR-15' 
and a.end_time <='03-MAR-15' and a.operation='UPDATE USER';
```

This one takes less than 4 seconds.

I don't understand why the second one goes so much faster.

Comment: Can you post the explain plan for the query?

Comment: What is the database of the start_time and end_time fields?  You are treading them as strings, but they are DATE types, no?  If so, then you need to use the proper data types when binding the parameters.

Comment: check v$sql_plan, when the query is running. Oracle also has something like "environment", which can influence the exec. plan. It might be optimizer_goal, case sensitivity, sorting according to national charset or even the size of io buffers.

Comment: @OldProgrammer start_time and end_time are both timestamp I tried using timestamp as data type but I got no improvement, also tried a.start_time >=to_timestamp(?) and got the same results

Answer (score 2):

I was using an old JDBC driver, I was using the driver for the 9i version and the DB is 11g.

I updated the JDBC driver and now the JDBC call runs as fast as in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and using `setInt` instead of `setString` where possible do the trick. 
Select takes 0.07s in Oracle developer, and 0.7s vs 4s using a prepared statement in Java. 
I used ojdbc6 11.2.0.4. 
Newer drivers (ojdbc8 12.2 or 18.3) eliminated the difference but also work slightly slower in both cases (~1s).